# FancyUpload timeout issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using FancyUpload with asp.net page.

It is working fine but when I try to upload a little heavy file say 5 MB it shows timeout error. Can u please guide where time limit can be increased or what else I should do to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the particulars of FancyUpload, but you are probably looking for a setting either in your project's web.config file or your IIS settings. You might have to try a few different settings before you get it right. One of the candidates is the maxRequestLength attribute in this example, 4000 here represents 4000kb:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4000"
    enable = "True"
    requestLengthDiskThreshold="512
    useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="True"
    executionTimeout="45"
    versionHeader="1.1.4128"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

[msdn resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28VS.80%29.aspx)